# How can i make this custom expander a non-hardcoded height?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded some code for a custom expander and have changed it to the way I want, with one exception.  The Height is hard-coded to 100 when expanded.  I need this to act like the normal expander and set the height to accomodate whatever is in the control.  Here is the XAML pertaining to that, you'll notice the Value="100" there, I tried Auto but I am forced to enter a double value as it is currently.  Any ideas?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}" x:Key="MyExpander">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <!--<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource titleText}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">

                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="strbExpand">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1200000" Value="100"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="strbCollapse">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="100"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1200000" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>


                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="3" >
                    <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
                        <ToggleButton FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                      Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                      FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" Margin="1,1,1,0" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0" x:Name="HeaderSite" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                        <Border Background="{DynamicResource ShadeBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" x:Name="border" Margin="1,1,1,1" Height="0" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1,1,1,1"  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource strbExpand}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard  Storyboard="{StaticResource strbCollapse}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Down">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Bottom" />
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom" />
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you can do this by tweaking `Height` with the `Tag` property in combination.

something like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyExpander"
        TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <!--  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource titleText}"/>  -->
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Key="strbExpand">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.12"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"
                              To="1" />
          </Storyboard>
          <Storyboard x:Key="strbCollapse">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.12"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"
                              To="0" />
          </Storyboard>
          <local:VariableHeightAnimationConverter x:Key="VariableHeightAnimationConverter" />
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                CornerRadius="3"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

          <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
            <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite"
                          MinWidth="0"
                          MinHeight="0"
                          Margin="1,1,1,0"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}"
                          FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                          FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                          FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" />
            <Border x:Name="border"
                    Margin="1,1,1,1"
                    Background="{DynamicResource ShadeBrush}"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                    CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
              <Border.Tag>
                <sys:Double>0.0</sys:Double>
              </Border.Tag>
              <Border.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VariableHeightAnimationConverter}">
                  <Binding ElementName="ExpandSite"
                            Path="ActualHeight" />
                  <Binding Path="Tag"
                            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                </MultiBinding>
              </Border.Height>
              <!--  ScrollViewer to allow us to compute the actual required height of the ContentPresenter -->
              <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"
                                  Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                  Focusable="false" />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
          </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                    Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource strbExpand}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource strbCollapse}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
          </Trigger>

          <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection"
                    Value="Down">
            <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite"
                    Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                    Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderSite"
                    Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                    Value="Top" />
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderSite"
                    Property="Style"
                    Value="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" />
          </Trigger>
          <!--
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
          -->
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the converter:

```
public class VariableHeightAnimationConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]) * System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new Exception("Not implemented");
  }
}
```